# How to make "\\" a string in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

i am making my own py package that is a fun package but in this part i have a prob:

```
import time
for x in range (0,5):  
    b = "||"
    print (b, end="\r")
    time.sleep(1)
    b = "//"
    print (b, end="\r")
    time.sleep(1)
    b = "--"
    print (b, end="\r")
    time.sleep(1)
    b = "\\"
    print (b, end="\r")
    time.sleep(1)
```

in `b = "\\"` the "\\" is taken as a path not string so how do i make it a string?

Comment: You need to use either `b = r"\\"` or `b = "\\\\"`. Read about escaping in [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the line:

```
b = '\\'
```

to

```
b = '\\\\'
```

`\` is the escape character so in order to use it you have to double it. Nothing to do with path.